# Using java to approximate pi with the first 8 terms of the sequence

Tags: java, pi

I'm just starting out with programming and need to do an assignment for class where I approximate pi using the first 8 terms in the sequence. I need to do this by creating a variable 'nextTerm' with initial value 1, variable 'denominator' with initial value 1, and variable 'series' with initial value 0. I get the first term when I run it, but then it only shows a line of zeros. I honestly have no clue what I'm doing.

```
public class ApproxPI
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int nextTerm = 1;
        int denominator = 1;
        int series = 0;

        for (int denominator = 1; denominator <= 8; denominator++) {
            series = ((-1 * ((-1 * nextTerm) / denominator)) * 4);
            System.out.println("Pi is approximately" + series);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you update `nextTerm` ever? It will always equal `1`, an `int`, with the code you show. So your loop will be equivalent to:

```
series = ( -1 * (( -1 * 1 ) / denominator )) / 4;
```

or equivalently

```
series = ( -1 * ( -1 / denominator )) / 4;
```

or

```
series = ( 1 / denominator ) / 4;
```

On each pass, because it is `int` arithmetic which throws away fractions:

```
( 1 / 1 ) / 4 => 1 / 4 => 0
( 1 / 2 ) / 4 => 0 / 4 => 0
( 1 / 3 ) / 4 => 0 / 4 => 0
. . .
( 1 / 8 ) / 4 => 0 / 4 => 0
```

Don't use `int` arithmetic. Don't use `float`, either, use `double`, for both the variables and the literals. You will never be able to calculate π using only `int` values.

Also, even if you got that right, your output would look something like:

```
Pi is approximately3
Pi is approximately1
Pi is approximately4
Pi is approximately1
Pi is approximately5
. . .
```

which might not be exactly what you intend.

This kind of manual walkthrough of the algorithm I was taught to call a "pencil test". Follow the logic precisely with (virtual) pencil and paper to see what it really does, not what you think it does.

You don't need to declare and initialize `denominator` twice. You do need to fix the use of `nextTerm`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know method this is to calculate PI but you surely should initialize your float and 1.0 instead of 1.
e.x

float nextTerm = 1.0; instead of int nextTerm = 1.0.

Do this for every variable to ensure the functionality

Comment: This explanation lacked the explanation of why `int` calculation didn't work, and should have recommended `double` rather than `float`. It also missed the misuse of `nextTerm`.